# Service Worker tracking in push notification

Tags: javascript, push-notification, service-worker

i want to know how we can track back service worker click event after push notification displayed.
i had registered service worker and send back push notification but now i want to track back the notification click event whether user opened notification and discard it.

```
self.addEventListener('push', function(event) { 
    const analyticsPromise = pushReceivedTracking(); 
    const pushInfoPromise = fetch('api/subscriber/msg/')
        .then(function(response) { return response.json(); })
        .then(function(response) {
            const title = response.data.userName + ' says...'; 
            const message = response.data.message; 
            return self.registration.showNotification(title, { body: message }); 
        }); 

    const promiseChain = Promise.all([ analyticsPromise, pushInfoPromise ]); 
    event.waitUntil(promiseChain);
 })
```

Comment: Can you share some of the code you've written so far? Can you describe the problem you're having?

Comment: self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
  const analyticsPromise = pushReceivedTracking();
  const pushInfoPromise = fetch('api/subscriber/msg/')
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(response) {
      const title = response.data.userName + ' says...';
      const message = response.data.message;

      return self.registration.showNotification(title, {
        body: message
      });
    });

  const promiseChain = Promise.all([
    analyticsPromise,
    pushInfoPromise
  ]);

  event.waitUntil(promiseChain);
});

Answer (score 1):

You can handle the [NotificationEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NotificationEvent) in your Service Worker:

```
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function (event) {
  event.notification.close();
  // track the notification click here
});
```

Note also you can add button to your notification - right now you'd only track just clicks into the notification itself.